# Is it possible to automatically re-share files shared to a Google account?

Tags: google-drive, sharing, file-sharing

Is it possible to set up one Google Account so that it automatically re-shares anything shared with it to another account?

I tried doing it with IFTTT, but the Google Drive Channel has no Triggers, only Actions.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like something you can probably do with the Zapier [Google Drive integrations](https://zapier.com/zapbook/google-drive/).

In particular you might check out this person has [created a Zap template](https://zapier.com/zapbook/google-drive/google-drive/28734/google-drive-new-file-in-folder-to-google-drive-copy-file-from-trigger/) that does basically that.